# Dell Data Collector Manager not showing Storage Center

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, dell, network-storage

In one of our environments, Dell Enterprise Manager Data Collector doesn't seem to connect to my Storage Centre. The logs shows that "Storage Centre Controller Cannot connect to the configured Enterprise Manager, configured Enterprise Manager has been disabled"

I've logged into the web client of the storage centre and cannot see anyway to configure/change/enable an Enterprise Manager. This was all set up by the Dell Engineer so I wasn't involved in the initial set up. I've spoken with CoPilot support and they're currently drawing a blank - so little nervous about what is causing this issue as data doesn't seem to be getting collected.

Dell Enterprise Manager 2015 R3
Dell Enterprise Manageer Data Collector 2015 R3

Not sure where to find Storage Centre OS version info?

Not sure what other info you would require, so just give me a shout and i'll try my best.

Thanks,

Michael